# How do you prevent bootstrap-datepicker from clearing existing value from input if no date is selected?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have have a div with a user's date of birth pre-populated with php:

```
<div id="datepicker" class="input-group date">
    <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dob" name="dob" value="<?php $date = new DateTime($this->swimmers->dob); echo $date->format('d/m/Y');?>"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
<script>     
    $('.container .input-group.date').datepicker({
    startDate: "01/01/1900",
    endDate: "01/01/2100",
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
    });
</script>
```

Bootstrap is setup and working correctly however, when the "dob" input gets and loses focus without making a date selection it clears the value that was pre-populated.

This however doesn't happen if a date has been selected via the datepicker and then the input gets and loses focus.

How can the pre-populated value be kept in the field if someone clicks in it?

Edit: The first time you make a date selection, it clears the pre-populated value but doesn't insert the selected date until you make a date selection a second time.

Update: Working code updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't tell for sure without more of an example but the problem is probably that the `$this->swimmers->dob` string you are giving to the input is not recognised as a date format by bootstrap-datepicker. You can define the date format it uses by adding the `data-date-format` attribute to your input.

For example if you were using a MySQL formatted date or PHP's DateTime object with `$date->format('Y-m-d')` you could use:

```
<div id="datepicker" class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dob" name="dob" value="<?php echo $this->swimmers->dob;?>" data-date-format="yy-mm-dd"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @steve-h.  Didn't have the date echoed out in the same format *face palm*

Comment: Hello Im struggling with the same issue but in jsp can u please have a look
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69939209/how-to-prevent-jquery-datepicker-from-clearing-date-on-submit-in-jsp

Answer (score 52):

Set Force parse value to false:
forceParse: false

```
    $(".applyDatepicker").datepicker({
            forceParse: false
    });
```

Comment: it did not work for me  var start = moment();
        var end = moment().add(2, "days");
        $("input[name=shifting_date]").daterangepicker({ 
         forceParse: false,
            startDate: start,
            endDate: end, 
            "applyClass"  : "btn-sm btn-success",

Comment: Thank you, @Datta. Worked for me as well. However, why does this work? I load the page with a valid date; click into field, click away, and without the above flag, the value is set to blank.

Comment: You Are Awesome Dear, It Worked Like Charm :)

Comment: Great answer Datta! I had this problem, and also a problem where tabbing out of the DatePicker would set it back to the placeholder of "mm/dd/yyyy". I spent the better part of a day on this issue. You rock!!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about its working in php but for mvc I got the same problem that Bootstrap would erase the value if the control gets and loses focus without making a date selection.

I found that Bootstrap erases the value as it doesn't recognize the value set by

```
$('#dtControl').val(nextMonth);
```

I am working with bootstrap v3.1.1 and the following code worked for me

```
$('#dtControl').datepicker('setDate', nextMonth);
```

to populate the datepicker control. This way Bootstrap recognizes the date and doesn't erase it if control gets and loses focus

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when a user clicked on the same date twice. The field would "toggle" between the date clicked on and a blank field. I basically didn't want it to be empty at any stage, so here's how I got around that, partly thanks to Waqas's answer:

```
var datepickerContainer = $('#datepicker');

datepickerContainer.datepicker({
    startDate: "01/01/1900",
    endDate: "01/01/2100",
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
}).on('show', function() {
    datepickerContainer.datepicker.currentDate = $('input#dob').val(); //update this instance with the current value
}).on('changeDate', function(event) {
    var newDate = $('input#dob').val();
    if (newDate == '' || newDate == null) { //check if the new value is empty - if it is, then just set it back to the last known date for this instance
        datepickerContainer.datepicker('setDate', datepickerContainer.datepicker.currentDate);
    }
});
```

That keeps it relatively self-contained, by storing the last date value in that instance of the datepicker and results in no clearing of the input.

I know you solved this problem, but I figured this snippet might come in handy for someone else in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

When jQuery calls a handler, the **this** keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered. Futhermore, a non empty string will evaluate to **true**. Based on these facts, simply do a check in the event handler. See sample code below.

```
            .find( 'input[name=startDate]' )
                .datepicker( {format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'} )
                .on( 'changeDate', function() {
                    if( this.value ) { 
                        << do something >>
                    }
                });
```

NOTE: For efficiency and readability in code sample above, the DOM property **value** is checked, instead of wrapping **this** in a jQuery object and calling **val()** on it ( $( this ).val() ). This is a minor improvement, but it's a good practice to be as compact/simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to define the options at the global level:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.format = 'dd/mm/yyyy';
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.startDate = "0";
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.language = "es";
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.autoclose = true;
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.todayHighlight = true;
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.todayBtn = true;
$.fn.datepicker.defaults.weekStart = 1;
```

Now, when use update method, datepicker don't lost options.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dob').datepicker('update', '2011-03-05');
```

You can use like this. Although for me it was working by simply passing value to element by using `.val()` function.

Reference URL.
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html